# Getopt - filename as argument

Tags: c, unix

Let's say I made a C program that is called like this:

```
./something -d dopt filename
```

So `-d` is a command, `dopt` is an optional argument to `-d` and `filename` is an argument to `./something`, because I can also call `./something filename`.

What is the `getopt` form to represent get the filename?

Comment: There isn't one, in this case.  `getopt` gets _options_, which `filename` isn't in this case (it's required for both invocations of the command you've shown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use optstring `"d:"`

Capture `-d dopt` with `optarg` in the usual way. Then look at `optind` (compare it with `argc`), which tells you whether there are any non-option arguments left. If so, your filename is the first of these.

`getopt` doesn't specifically tell you what the non-option arguments are or check the number. It just tells you where they start (having first moved them to the end of the argument array, if you're in GNU's non-strict-POSIX mode)

Answer (score 4):

Check-out how [grep does it](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/grep/grep/src/grep.c?view=markup). At the end of `main()` you'll find:

```
if (optind < argc)
{
    do
    {
        char *file = argv[optind];
        // do something with file
    }
    while ( ++optind < argc);
}
```

The `optind` is the number of command-line options found by getopt. So this conditional/loop construct can handle all of the files listed by the user.