# How to get filename from command line

Tags: c, getopt

I'm aware questions of this nature have been asked on Stack Overflow before, but I wasn't able to achieve success even after reading some threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188666/getopt-filename-as-argument))([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210580/c-using-a-file-argument-with-getopt)).

I'm writing a C function that'll read in a filename that's specified as a command-line argument. But I also have room for **one** optional argument that comes before the filename.

Example execution (these three invocations are independent of each other):

```
./my_program -a foo.txt  // Standalone example #1
./my_program -b foo.txt  // Standalone example #2
./my_program foo.txt  // Standalone example #3
```

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int aflag = 0;
  int bflag = 0;
  int cflag = 0;
  int option;
  char *filename;

  while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1) {
    switch (option) {
    case 'a':
      aflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'b':
      bflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'c':
      cflag = 1;
      break;
    default:
      aflag = 1;  // If no flags are set, use "a"
      break;
    }
  }

  if (argc == 2) {
    filename = argv[1];
  } else if (argc == 3) {
    filename = argv[2];
  }

  printf("Flags: aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cflag = %d\n", aflag, bflag, cflag);
  printf("Got filename = %s\n", filename);
```

This **does** work for the case with **one** optional argument.

However, I was reading about `[optind]`([3](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optind)) and was wondering what the correct usage of it was so that I can get the filename. I couldn't seem to get it to work, and I don't know if using `if` statements like this is good style.

For example, right now this code is limited to **one** optional argument. But what if I later decide to add in a second argument? Then my above code won't work, since the `argv` index where the filename is located will have changed.

Is there a way -- presumably using `getind` and `getopt` -- to always grab the last argument as the filename, no matter how many (optional) arguments I specify before it?

Comment: After processing all option arguments, `if (argc > optindex) /* the next arguments will be your filename */`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "the next arguments will be your filename." Do you mean that `filename = argv[optind + 1]` in every situation?

Comment: Let's say you have `"-f:"` for the filename option in your options list. You can pass `"-f filename"` on the command line and no additional arguments will remain unprocessed. Now let's say you just provide `"filename"` as the arguments on the command line. 1 additional arguments will remain which you can use as your filename.

Comment: strongly suggest that ALL filename arguments be preceded with a `-f` argument so that the call to `getopt()` can simply access `filename` like any other command line argument

Answer (score 3):

When you are making friends with `getopt`, understand that `getopt` basically parses your command line, matching options and any arguments to options requiring requiring a value. All other non-option arguments are reordered so they appear at the end of your argument list. When you loop as you do normally checking, for example `while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "f:ohv")) != -1)`, any command line arguments that were not options and were not the required values for option will remain beginning at `argv[optind]`. So when your argument processing loop is done, you check `if (optind < argc)` to determine if you have additional command line arguments available that were not processed in your `getopt` loop.

Let's take a reasonably complete example handling a filename, either given after the `"-f"` option or simply as the first non-argument option that remains after all options are processed (or we will read `stdin` if no additional options remain -- but note, in that case you can't have additional options or the first will be taken as the filename to read)

One of the easiest/most convenient ways to handle processing arguments is simply to declare an options array which you initialize as all zeros. Then as you process options you use your `opts` array where each element either holds the index of the corresponding option in `argv`, or a flag (e.g. set to `1` if the option is set), or the value resulting from a conversion (say if you had `"-n:"` to input some number, then with your command line containing `"-n 4"`, you could convert and store the actual value `4` at the array index associated with the `"-n"` option (instead of the `argv` index you would have to convert to a numeric value later)).

The purpose of your `processopts()` function is loop with `getopt()` and to fully turn any options into usable values for the rest of your program to use. By using an option array, this makes it easy to pass as a parameter to a function to process all your options. By making the type of the option array `long`, you have the native width for and `strtol` conversions available, as well as being able to handle both positive and negative values.

So let's look at an example using a `processopts()` function. In `main()` or wherever you will call your `processopts()`, you simply declare an array where each element will correspond to some option you will process and hold a meaningful value after that option is processed, e.g.

```
#define NOPTS   8   /* max options for sizing opts array */
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    long opts[NOPTS] = {0};  /* initialize opitons array all zero */
    ...
    int optindex = processopts (argc, argv, opts);  /* process all options */
```

So above you have declared your `opts` array and passed it along with `argc,` and `argv` to your `processopts()` function. Your `processopts()` function would then do something similar to:

```
/** process command line options with getopt.
 *  values are made available through the 'opts' array.
 *  'optind' is returned for further command line processing.
 */
int processopts (int argc, char **argv, long *opts)
{
    int opt;

    /* set any default values in *opts array here */

    while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "f:ohv")) != -1) {  /* getopt loop */
        switch (opt) {
            case 'f':       /* filename */
                opts[0] = optind - 1;
                break;
            case 'o':       /* some generic option 'o' */
                opts[1] = 1;
                break;
            case 'h':       /* help */
                help (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            case 'v':       /* show version information */
                printf ("%s, version %s\n", PACKAGE, VERSION);
                exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default :       /* ? */
                fprintf (stderr, "\nerror: invalid or missing option.\n");
                help (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    /* set argv index for filename if arguments remain */
    if (!opts[0] && argc > optind) opts[0] = optind++;

    return optind;  /* return next argument index */
}
```

**Note** above if the `"-f filename"` option was given `opts[0]` is set to the index of the next argument (the filename) and then the test at the end to determine whether to check for additional arguments to use as the filename is skipped because `opts[0]` is no longer `0`. But if `opts[0]` was not set, the **index** for first non-option argument would be stored in `opts[0]`. Regardless whether the filename was taken following `"-f"` or read as the first non-option argument you to then call `fopen (argv[opts[0]], "r")` to open the file in `main()`.

**Note also** that `optind` is returned allowing you to determine if there were additional (or extra) arguments that were not processed in your `getopt` loop, so you can check `if (optind < argc)` back in `main()` and handle the extra arguments as you see fit.

Putting it together in a short (for getopt) example, you could experiment with something like the following to pass the filename after `"-f"` or anywhere else without `"-f"` so long as it is the first non-option argument that remains, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for getopt */

#define PACKAGE "getopt_example"
#define VERSION "0.01"

#define NOPTS   8   /* max options for sizing opts array */
#define MAXC 1024   /* max characters for buffer */

int processopts (int argc, char **argv, long *opts);
void help (int xcode);
size_t rmcrlf (char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    long opts[NOPTS] = {0};  /* initialize opitons array all zero */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    size_t idx = 0;
    int optindex = processopts (argc, argv, opts);

    /* use filename provided as following "-f" option or provided as
     * 1st non-option argument (stdin by default)
     */
    FILE *fp = opts[0] ? fopen (argv[opts[0]], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* indicate whether the option '-o' was set */
    printf ("\nthe option '-o' %s set.\n\n", opts[1] ? "is" : "is not");

    printf (" line : len - contents\n\n");
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read ouput length/lines from file */
        size_t l = rmcrlf (buf);    /* get line length, trim line ending */
        printf (" %4zu : %3zu - %s\n", idx++, l, buf);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    if (optindex < argc)    /* check whether additional options remain */
        printf ("\nwarning: %d options unprocessed.\n\n", argc - optindex);

    for (int i = optindex; i < argc; i++)   /* output unprocessed options */
        printf (" %s\n", argv[i]);

    return 0;
}

/** process command line options with getopt.
 *  values are made available through the 'opts' array.
 *  'optind' is returned for further command line processing.
 */
int processopts (int argc, char **argv, long *opts)
{
    int opt;

    /* set any default values in *opts array here */

    while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "f:ohv")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'f':       /* filename */
                opts[0] = optind - 1;
                break;
            case 'o':       /* some generic option 'o' */
                opts[1] = 1;
                break;
            case 'h':       /* help */
                help (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            case 'v':       /* show version information */
                printf ("%s, version %s\n", PACKAGE, VERSION);
                exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default :       /* ? */
                fprintf (stderr, "\nerror: invalid or missing option.\n");
                help (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    /* set argv index for filename if arguments remain */
    if (!opts[0] && argc > optind) opts[0] = optind++;

    return optind;  /* return next argument index */
}

/** display help */
void help (int xcode)
{
    xcode = xcode ? xcode : 0;

    printf ("\n %s, version %s\n\n"
            "  usage:  %s [-hv -f file (stdin)] [file]\n\n"
            "  Reads each line from file, and writes line, length and contents\n"
            "  to stdout.\n\n"
            "    Options:\n\n"
            "      -f file    specifies filename to read.\n"
            "                 (note: file can be specified with or without -f option)\n"
            "      -o         generic option for example.\n"
            "      -h         display this help.\n"
            "      -v         display version information.\n\n",
            PACKAGE, VERSION, PACKAGE);

    exit (xcode);
}

/** remove newline or carriage-return from 's'.
 *  returns new length on success, -1 of 's' is NULL.
 */
size_t rmcrlf (char *s)
{
    size_t len;

    if (!s) return 0;                       /* validate s not NULL */

    s[(len = strcspn (s, "\r\n"))] = 0;     /* nul-terminate saving len */

    return len;     /* return len */
}
```

(the program will tell you if the `"-o"` option `"is"` or `"is not"` set, and thereafter just read the filename found in the command line arguments (or `stdin` if no filename or additional argument was provided) and spit out the line index (0 - N-1), the length of the line and finally the line itself followed by any additional arguments not processed by `getopt` or in the `processopts()` function.

Example command line could be:

```
$ ./bin/getopt_min -f dat/captnjack.txt extra1 extra2
```

(read file `dat/captnjack.txt` and shows there were two extra arguments not processed)

```
$ ./bin/getopt_min dat/captnjack.txt -o extra1 extra2
```

(same)

```
$ ./bin/getopt_min -o <dat/captnjack.txt
```

(file read on `stdin`)

Finally the `"-h"` and `"-v"` options just cause the help or version information to be displayed.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. It takes a while to digest `getopt`, that's normal, just keep the man page open and work through a couple of examples.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. This will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From the page you linked:

> If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1. Then optind is the index in argv of the first argv-element that is not an option.

So in place of

```
if (argc == 2) {
    filename = argv[1];
  } else if (argc == 3) {
    filename = argv[2];
  }
```

you simply want

```
filename = argv[optind];
```

Note that if no arguments were specified after the options (e.g. if your program was invoked as simply `./my_program -a`, then this will set `filename` to `NULL`, and you should be prepared to handle this accordingly.  You can also detect this case explicitly if you wish:

```
if (optind < argc) {
    filename = argv[optind];
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -a|-b|-c filename\n", argv[0]);
    exit(2);
}
```

Comment: If I write `filename = argv[optind]`, then when I include an optional argument, `filename` becomes `(null)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "include an optional argument".  Can you give an example of the command line you are talking about?

Comment: @WaterGuy: If you mean you ran `./my_program -c foo`, then that's expected: when you included `c:` in the `getopt` string, then `foo` is interpreted as an argument to the `-c` option, and `optarg` will be set to point to it when `getopt` returns `'c'`.  In this case `foo` is part of the options, and there are no arguments left after option parsing is completed.  So in that case `optind` is set equal to `argc` and `argv[argc]` is a null pointer, as I explained in the answer.  Your `printf` apparently prints out as the string `"(null)"`, but as I mentioned you should really handle that case.

Comment: By optional argument, I mean that the flags (e.g. `-a`) are optional to add. If a flag is not present, it automatically defaults to `-a`. In this latter case, if I don't include `-a`, I get `(null)` as the `filename`.

So I guess this is the `else` case in your code above. How would I then grab the file name? Would it be best to just use `argv[1]`?

Comment: @WaterGuy I still don't follow you, and I'm not sure we are both using the terms "argument" and "flag" consistently.  I'll repeat: can you give a specific example of the complete command line you are talking about?  It sounds to me like you mean `./my_program foo` but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm referring to `./my_program foo`.

Comment: @WaterGuy: That's not the behavior I see, so maybe you could post the current version of your code with `argv[optind]`.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/W1ZmTHME) is what I am using.  When I run `./my_program foo`, I get the expected output `Flags: aflag = 0, bflag = 0, cflag = 0\n
Got filename = foo`

Comment: @WaterGuy: On an unrelated note, your `default:` case will not result in `aflag` being set when no options are passed.  `getopt` will always return either `'a','b','c'` or `-1` so the `default:` case will never execute.  You would have to explicitly write something like `if (!bflag && !cflag) aflag = 1;`.